# Relative path on File.ReadAllLines method

Tags: c#-2.0, file.readalllines

My code access a file which is in "Conf" directory inside my project directory. I am currently opening the file using absolute path like below:

```
File.ReadAllLines("C:\project name\Conf\filename");
```

I was thinikng if it's possible to use the relative path like

```
File.ReadAllLines("/Conf/filename");
```

But it's not working; as expected it throws exception. I did checked MSDN (link below) but seems "ReadAllLines()" methods doesn't accept relative path.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

Any idea, how can I use the relative path instead using absolute path?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my favorite way of doing it.

1. Make your file an embedded resource.

   ```
       /// <summary>
       /// This class must be in the same folder as the embedded resource
       /// </summary>
   public class GetResources
   {       
       private static readonly Type _type = typeof(GetResources);

       public static string Get(string fileName)
       {
           using (var stream = 
           _type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
          (_type.Namespace + "." + fileName))
           {
               if (stream != null)
                   using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                   {
                       return reader.ReadToEnd();
                   }
           }
           throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);
       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in MSDN you cannot use a relative path, however you might be able to use either `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple, use the following:

```
string current_path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

string[] lines_from_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(current_path + "/Conf/filename");

...additional black magic here...
```